# return the array of the key-value pairs of object js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to return the array of the key-value pairs of object via a method. I'm using **Object.entries()**, but it changes the order of properties(in example you can see that numerical property is moved to the first place in returned array).

```js
Object.toPairs = function (obj) {return Object.entries(obj);}

var aloha = {
  this: 'is',
  not: 'so',
  hard: 'really o_O ?!',
  a: 'xxx',
  1: '-----',
};
Object.toPairs(aloha)
```

result is

```
[ [ '1', '-----' ], [ 'this', 'is' ], [ 'not', 'so' ], [ 'hard', 'really o_O ?!' ], [ 'a', 'xxx' ] ]
```

How can it be properly solved?

Comment: Solve it by sorting if you can. Or be safe and use an array of objects. There are rules for the ordering, which I think now put numeric indexes first and sequential. Before that it was implementation defined, so there were no guarantees.

Comment: If you can, change `aloha` to a `Map`, it respects order when you insert. Otherwise you're going to have a hard time with hashes.

Comment: How do you want the solution to look like?

Comment: solution for given example should look like this >>
[
  ['this', 'is'],
  ['not', 'so'], 
  ['hard', 'really o_O ?!'], 
  ['a', 'xxx'], 
  [1, '-----']
]